# Mapbox Unit Testing - Failed to initialize WebGL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, mapbox

I'm currently using Mapbox for a React application and I'm trying to perform unit testing but it doesn't seem to work. I've set the Mapbox testMode to true and it still gives me an error saying:

```
Error: Failed to initialize WebGL.
at new Map (C:\Users\...\node_modules\mapbox-gl\dist\mapbox-gl.js:35:427889)
```

The following snippet is how we generate the mapbox component which also receives a test variable to set the testMode.

```
const MapBox = (props: MapBoxProps) => {
  const { floorPlan, isTest } = props;
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(48);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(25);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1.8);

  const createMapbox = () => {
    if (!isTest) {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = appConfig.MAPBOX_TOKEN;
    }
    const mb = new mapboxgl.Map({
      attributionControl: false,
      container: mapContainer.current,
      testMode: isTest,
      style: {
        version: 8,
        sources: {},
        layers: [
          {
            id: "background",
            type: "background",
            paint: {
              "background-color": "white",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom,
      maxZoom: 6,
      dragRotate: false,
    });
    mb.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({ showCompass: false }));
    return mb;
  };
  return <div
        data-cr="mapbox-container"
        ref={mapContainer}
      />;
}
```

And the code for testing our **CustomMapBox** component is as follows:

```
const renderMapBox = () => {
  return render(<CustomMapBox floorPlan={mockedFloorPlan} isTest={true} />);
};

describe("MapBox", () => {
  it("renders without error and two floors", () => {
    renderMapBox();
  });
}
```

I've tried to:

- Change versions
- Change jest configurations
- Set mapbox testMode to true

And nothing seems to work.

Versions:

```
"mapbox-gl": "^2.8.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
"jest": "^27.3.1",
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.
Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: From the error I suspect, this might more be an issue with your unit testing environment not supporting WebGL than with your code

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to your setupTest.ts

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'

jest.mock('mapbox-gl', () => ({
  Map: jest.fn(() => ({}))
}))
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
mapboxgl.Map.prototype = {
  getBearing: jest.fn(),
  getCenter: jest.fn(),
  getPitch: jest.fn(),
  getZoom: jest.fn(),
  off: jest.fn(),
  on: jest.fn(),
  remove: jest.fn(),
  //your map functions used in your component
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).